# Question regarding the maximum principle for harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

The principle is formulated the following way:

Let $h$ be a harmonic function on a domain $D$ in $\mathbb{C}$. If $h$ extends continuously to $\partial D$ and $h\leq 0$ on $\partial D$, then $h\leq 0$ on $D.$

The book states that this is with respect to the Riemann Sphere and $\textbf{not}$ $\mathbb{C}$, but I have trouble understanding the theorem in terms of that.

Take for instance $h(z)=\Re (z)$   on $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:Re (z)>0\}$

What is the image of D onto the Riemann Sphere? Isn't it the halfsphere? Shouldn't the extension then be continuous?

Answer (score 0):

No. If $D$ is the upper half-plane then the boundary *in* the Riemann sphere includes $\infty$.

Comment: Could you elaborate why this isn't a continuous extension?